# How to create this modal in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, modal-dialog

How can I create a modal component that will work like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PGI0.gif)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: thats alot of work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice tutorial [here](https://dev.to/johannawad/creating-a-swipe-up-bottom-drawer-in-react-native-no-external-libraries-3ng1) on how to make the drawer from scratch. You can then add then add a `<TextInput ref={ref} />` component with a ref assigned and use the `focus()` method on it once the drawer is opened. More on the TextInput [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#focus).